# Other Users Cannot Connect to SQL Data Connection

Tags: excel-2013, powerpivot

I have been banging my head for hours now trying to figure out this issue.  Currently, I have an Excel 2013 file that I created with a few pivot charts.  The pivot charts are connected to SQL Server 2012.  I personally can refresh the data without any issues on my end, however whenever someone else tries to 
open the database connection they receive the following error.  I have tested this on multiple users and each one experiences the same error.  Any suggestions on what's going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your users need to instal the same SQL Server driver you use, or you need to change yours to match their drivers:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2022518/error-message-class-not-registered-when-you-update-powerpivot-data